# Multiple EpochCounter's in a plugin

Tags: newrelic-platform

I'm trying to create a custom plugin to track counts and rates of various things. I'm new to Ruby and NewRelic so I'm taking the wikimedia plugin and hacking at it to learn since it did a simplified version of what I'm trying. In my setup, I have this --

```
def setup_metrics
  @doc_creation_rate = NewRelic::Processor::EpochCounter.new
  @consumer_online_rate = NewRelic::Processor::EpochCounter.new
  @consumer_offline_rate = NewRelic::Processor::EpochCounter.new
  @event_rate = NewRelic::Processor::EpochCounter.new
  @task_queue_rate = NewRelic::Processor::EpochCounter.new
end
```

I quickly found that my rate values were fairly incomprehensible so I added some debugging code to the processor to see what it was doing. I saw quickly that the last_value and last_time were being used by each successive rate calc --

```
last value: 0.0, last time: Thu Aug 08 18:03:28 -0500 2013, cur value: 33.0, cur time; Thu Aug 08 18:04:27 -0500 2013, rate: 0.553659969226572
last value: 33.0, last time: Thu Aug 08 18:04:27 -0500 2013, cur value: 9.0, cur time; Thu Aug 08 18:04:27 -0500 2013, rate: -172661.870503597
last value: 9.0, last time: Thu Aug 08 18:04:27 -0500 2013, cur value: 9.0, cur time; Thu Aug 08 18:04:27 -0500 2013, rate: 0.0
last value: 9.0, last time: Thu Aug 08 18:04:27 -0500 2013, cur value: 0.0, cur time; Thu Aug 08 18:04:27 -0500 2013, rate: -94736.8421052632
last value: 0.0, last time: Thu Aug 08 18:04:27 -0500 2013, cur value: 4012.0, cur time; Thu Aug 08 18:04:27 -0500 2013, rate: 62687500.0
last value: 4012.0, last time: Thu Aug 08 18:04:27 -0500 2013, cur value: 0.0, cur time; Thu Aug 08 18:04:27 -0500 2013, rate: -42680851.0638298
```

Is it possible to use EpochCounter in the way that I'm trying to use it? If so, how? Is there a better way?

Thanks!

--
Marc

Comment: @Marc Can you give more information about what you are trying to do? Theoretically, it could be appropriate to create a new counter for these different rates you are trying to capture in your plugin, but it really depends on what you are doing with the data.

Comment: Just trying to collect about a half dozen counters (at this point) and store the counts and rates of change in NewRelic. I was hoping the EpochCounter would do the magic of keeping last values/timestamps for the rate calculation part without having to do that in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Stupid copy-pasta mistake but I learned a lot about ruby modules and objects as a result =) I was reusing the same variable/namespace.

```
report_metric("Streaming/Rate/Online Consumers", "consumers/sec", @event_rate.process(total_consumers_online))
report_metric("Streaming/Rate/Offline Consumers", "consumers/sec", @event_rate.process(total_consumers_offline))
report_metric("Streaming/Rate/Events", "events/sec", @event_rate.process(total_events))
```

should have been --

```
report_metric("Streaming/Rate/Online Consumers", "consumers/sec", @consumer_online_rate.process(total_consumers_online))
report_metric("Streaming/Rate/Offline Consumers", "consumers/sec", @consumer_offline_rate.process(total_consumers_offline))
report_metric("Streaming/Rate/Events", "events/sec", @event_rate.process(total_events))
```